# Set up development environment for Typo3 project

Tags: git, typo3, development-environment

We have to set a fool development environment for the CMS Typo3 project.
We are three developers who need to commit to git master branch and so on.
But how you all know - for typo3 is not so easy to work in team. Cos we have different DB and a lot of things must be changed through the admin panel.

Maybe some have a thoughts about this? Maybe someone have the same experience?

Answer (score 1):

You can override all settings in the `typo3conf/LocalConfiguration.php` in the file `typo3conf/AdditionalConfiguration.php`. It is executed after the local configuration was calculated.

Just fill it with something like this:

```
<?php
    $GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['DB']['host'] = 'localhost';
    $GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['DB']['port'] = '33306';
    $GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['DB']['user'] = 'myuser';
    $GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['DB']['password'] = 's3cr3t';
    $GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['DB']['database'] = 'myDB';
```

You can remove it from version control (or include a file in it, and remove that from version control), and fill it differently in each development environment.

Also, there were application contexts introduced in TYPO3 6.2, you can use them in conjunction with the `AdditionalConfiguration.php`. [Ticket for this topic](https://forge.typo3.org/issues/49988).